# Stop Attachment image names from taking top level permalink

Tags: images, attachments, permalinks

I don't know why but images uploaded to my site in posts are getting a top level permalink. So if I upload an image into a post called "Apple" then it gets an attachment page at mysite.com/apple and that is a big problem for me. How can add a path between my top level and image attachment page name?

Comment: The question is more like: Why does this happen? Please write a quick plugin for that and update your post, so we can try to debug this in our own installations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't link to attachment pages anywhere on your site and it won't matter what permalink they have. Search engines only see what you make public.

BTW another thing you can try is to upload only from within the post/page edit screen. That way attachments take up the parent post/page permalink. Sort of like

example.com/post-name/attachment-name.

Comment: what's happenig is Im using a front end post form so user can submit but if they submit a image with a name of someone it takes up that top level url. So when I want to go and make wiki style pages about people they are taken by these images.